# How can I make konsole re-arrange lines on the terminal based on a change in window size?

Tags: kubuntu, konsole

On some computers I work with, if you change the window size, those lines which have already been printed to the screen dynamically change to fit the new version. My new installation of Kubuntu 14.04 does not include that feature with konsole.

How can I make konsole do this?

Answer (score 2):

This may not be a konsole feature, but something encountered in other terminals.  (k)ubuntu 14.04 is not new, so these bug-reports are probably relevant:

- [Bug 196998 - Konsole should reflow the text when resizing](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196998)
- [Bug 62380 - disable wordwrap in konsole](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=62380)

Perhaps you were using Fedora or something of that nature, where almost any patch may be applied — the KDE bug reports mention patches for this feature.  Ubuntu on the other hand inherits almost all of its packages (and patches) from Debian, which operates differently.